# Convert date fomat "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy" to "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss" in Java

Tags: java, java-time

I have the code optimisation issue. Currently I am converting these two formats using java LocalDateTime. But it takes around 80 ms - 110 ms. This is increasing my response time as well. Is there an alternative and faster way to do this ??

here is my code :

```
value= Tue Jan 01 00:19:32 CET 1901

begindate = 1901-01-01T00:19:32
```

```java
private static DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern
("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy",Locale.ENGLISH);

LocalDateTime beginDate = LocalDateTime.parse(value, formatter);

String Isoformat = beginDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)
```

Comment: Which does take longer: `parse` or `format`? How long does take each of them in ms? Have you considered grafting substrings (including `switch` over month names constants) from the input string to the output string builder with initial capacity, or right into the output stream? (No date/time validation or time offset, but if you trust the input...)

Comment: `Tue Jan 01 00:19:32 CET 1901` probably comes from an old-fashioned `java.util.Date` object. If you can get that object and not only the string, you won’t need to use time for parsing. Which I guess is probably what is taking the longer time, so should solve your issue.

Comment: How are you benchmarking this? That sounds like a *very* long time - suspiciously so, unless you're timing it on a really slow machine. Do you have any benchmark code that you could share with us? (As a comparison, the benchmarks I have for my Noda Time library in .NET show parsing and formatting each on the order of a few hundred nanoseconds - not this exact pattern, but I'd be surprised if this pattern made it *that* much slower.)

Comment: Except for the smallest throw-away programs don’t convert date and time from one string format to another. Keep your date and time in a proper date-time object. `Instant` or `ZonedDateTime` is probably a better choice than `LocalDateTime`. Only when you need to give string output, format into a string in the user’s desired time zone.

Comment: I have used the Java profiler to find out which part takes longer time. Parse is taking longer time than format. The date comes from Database which is stored in string format. I have a requirement to keep them in string format, as it's a part of json-ld response

Comment: time taken in LocalDateTime parse : 81 ms
time taken in LocalDateTime fomat : 0 ms  ; Calculating with : (Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() - time.getTimeInMillis())

Comment: Can you change the database schema to store the date and time as `timestamp with time zone` or `datetime`? That again will save you from parsing. (Converting all the data will take time, of course, but that’s only once.)

Comment: How many iterations are you testing for parsing time? Again, that seems like a *staggering* amount of time just to parse a single value. Here's a simple pseudo-benchmark... it doesn't use the proper benchmarking tools, but it's enough to show that 80ms is orders of magnitude higher than reality, at least on my machine: https://gist.github.com/jskeet/2938b1846931746b8950dd42cd63fe9c - that shows 1400ns per parse operation. By contrast, 80ms is 80,000,000ns. I don't believe my machine is 57,000x faster than yours :)

Comment: @JonSkeet I ran the program in my machine :  I get this , evidently my machine is bit slower then.                                           
1901000000
Nanos per parse: 18600

Comment: @Srishti: Is that running it *not* in a debugger? Even if that's the case, it's still only 10x slower... it's showing 18 *microseconds* per parse operation, which is a lot, lot faster than 81 *milliseconds*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**: The comments by Jon Skeet and finally yourself give the answer: The first time you parse a string, the time zone database and the locale data included with the JVM need to be loaded in order to parse `CET` (or other time zone abbreviation in the string). This takes time. The next times theses data are already loaded, so parsing is fast.

You can improve the parsing time of the first string if on program startup you have time to do some time zone operation so the data are loaded. You may try `ZoneId.systemDefault()` or `ZoneId.systemDefault().getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT, Locale.ENGLISH)` or simply parsing a (hardcoded) string like the ones in the database.

**Original answer**: Change the database schema to store the date and time as `timestamp with time zone` or `datetime`. This will save you from parsing. (If there’s data in your table already, converting it will take time, of course, but that’s only once and doesn’t happen while the user is waiting for a response.)

If you can’t change the database schema, here’s a more direct answer to your question. It’s ugly code because it’s written for optimization, so only use it as a last resort.

```
private static DateTimeFormatter monthFormatter
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM", Locale.ROOT);

    int m = Month.from(monthFormatter.parse(value.subSequence(4, 7))).getValue();
    if (m < 10) {
        return value.substring(value.length() - 4) + "-0" + m + '-' + value.substring(8, 10) + 'T' + value.substring(11, 19); 
    } else {
        return value.substring(value.length() - 4) + '-' + m + '-' + value.substring(8, 10) + 'T' + value.substring(11, 19); 
    }
```

On my 10 years old computer this reduced the time from 1.78 milliseconds to 0.73 ms per conversion, measured with `System.nanoTime()` on 100 conversions. A 59 % reduction compared to your code.

You may be able to get a further reduction if you make your own `HashMap` lookup of the month abbreviation instead of using a `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: I can see that loading TimeZones takes alot of time when the dates are converted the first time . If I add the same code just below it . It takes 1 ms only.